# How to exclude certain modelAttributes in JSON output (using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver)

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring MVC 3.1.0 project and I have configured a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` bean to automatically generate JSON output for a given endpoint (which uses `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView`).

I have a few controller methods which add data to the JSP page (via `model.addAttribute("foo", fooService.getFoo());`) that I don't want to appear in the JSON output.

I have tried adding a `@JsonIgnore` annotation to my service method `getFoo()` (which returns a `Map<String, String>`) but it doesn't work. I still see the foo object being marshalled in my JSON output when I hit that controller.

Can anyone suggest another way of achieving this or tell me why the `JsonIgnore` annotation is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MappingJacksonJsonView` serializes all the contents of the model into a json - all the objects that you have placed in your model object, so it does not matter if you have marked one of the service methods with `@JsonIgnore`, as long it ends up in the model which it does because of the call to `model.addAttribute("foo"..` it would get serialized. The fix could be simply to not add the model attribute, or to use `@ResponseBody` which will give you control over the specific response object that is being serialized.

Another option is to specify the exact keys that you will be using when configuring `MappingJacksonJsonView`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" name="jsonView">
<property name="modelKeys">
   <set>
    <value>model1</value>
    <value>model2</value>
   </set>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This particular page doesn't greatly benefit from having a JSON view so I could get away with excluding it completely. But this would require creating a new controller method with an explicit mapping to catch JSON requests and then simply return a 404 (ugly). I could try to programatically catch the JSON version (look inside the `HttpServletRequest`) and add an `if` statement around the `model.addAttribute()`? Also ugly... 'was hoping something simple **like** `@JsonIgnore` would be available.

Comment: I did see the `modelKeys` option but I have way too many models/controllers to be able to use this in a maintainable way.

Answer (score 0):

Extend MappingJackson2JsonView class and override filterMap(Map model) method.
In the filterMap method filter out keys with the name of modelAttributes you need to exclude.

```
public class MappingJackson2JsonViewExt extends MappingJackson2JsonView {
    private static final Set<String> EXCLUDED_KEYS = new HashSet<>();

    public static void excludeModelKey(final String key) {
        EXCLUDED_KEYS.add(key);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object filterModel(final Map<String, Object> model) {
        final Map<String, Object> filteredModel = model.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> {
                    final String key = e.getKey();
                    return !EXCLUDED_KEYS.contains(key);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        return super.filterModel(filteredModel);
    }
}
```